# Name or type of these connectors

Tags: connections

How are these springed ball connectors called? Can not find them without right name.

[image]

Comment: Pogo Pins si the usual term

Comment: For future reference, you should probably point to exactly what part of the component you are asking about.

Comment: I did. I asked about springed ball connectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring pin connector
Spring loaded connector
Spring-loaded connector
Spring loaded pin connector
Magnetic spring connector (obviously only if magnetic)

[Google image search "spring pin connector"](https://www.google.com/search?q=spring%20pin%20connector&tbm=isch)

[Mill-Max spring-loaded connector](https://www.mill-max.com/new_products/detail/74)

Answer (score 0):

[I found this link that is from the seller.](http://www.woodencamera.com/tool-less-lcd-evf-adapter-weapon-p/233800.htm)

It's a 26 pins adapter that they call:

> Tool-less LCD/EVF Adapter

I *believe* this is a unique product to the brand.

Comment: Dear Dat Ha. Thanks for your answer, but I am asking about the connector in the middle of this adapter.